# What kind of lock is placed on a row that's updated in a transaction?

Tags: transactions, locking, sql-server-2014, transaction-isolation

If I start a transaction with isolation level "read uncommitted" in SQL Server, then I read and update a particular row, is that row then locked by virtue of being part of a transaction?

If another transaction (also with read uncommitted) tries to read and update that row, will it be blocked as long as the first transaction has not yet completed?

Answer (score 0):

Read uncommitted isolation level does not put shared locks but put exclusive locks. So whether session 2 gets blocked by session one depends on the below scenario :

If the 2nd session is trying to update the row which is already having x lock by session 1. That is second session is trying to put x lock on the same row that session one has put x lock on will be blocked